# Upgrading from Fedora 17 to Fedora 20 (or higher)

Tags: linux, fedora, upgrade, yum

I'm trying to upgrade my fedora 17 install to a more recent version. I have tried the following methods, which don't work:

First, using fedup:

```
# yum install ./fedup-0.8.1-1.fc20.noarch.rpm
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, priorities, refresh-packagekit
Setting up Install Process
Examining ./fedup-0.8.1-1.fc20.noarch.rpm: fedup-0.8.1-1.fc20.noarch
Marking ./fedup-0.8.1-1.fc20.noarch.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package fedup.noarch 0:0.8.1-1.fc20 will be obsoleting
--> Processing Dependency: systemd >= 183 for package: fedup-0.8.1-1.fc20.noarch
---> Package preupgrade.noarch 0:1.1.10-2.fc17 will be obsoleted
--> Processing Dependency: preupgrade for package: PackageKit-0.7.6-1.fc17.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: PackageKit-0.7.6-1.fc17.x86_64 (@updates)
           Requires: preupgrade
           Removing: preupgrade-1.1.10-2.fc17.noarch (@koji-override-0/$releasever)
               preupgrade = 1.1.10-2.fc17
           Obsoleted By: fedup-0.8.1-1.fc20.noarch (/fedup-0.8.1-1.fc20.noarch)
               Not found
Error: Package: fedup-0.8.1-1.fc20.noarch (/fedup-0.8.1-1.fc20.noarch)
           Requires: systemd >= 183
           Installed: systemd-44-24.fc17.x86_64 (@updates)
               systemd = 44-24.fc17
           Available: systemd-44-8.fc17.i686 (fedora)
               systemd = 44-8.fc17
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 9 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
krb5-devel-1.10.2-12.fc17.x86_64 has missing requires of keyutils-libs-devel
krb5-devel-1.10.2-12.fc17.x86_64 has missing requires of libselinux-devel
libdb-5.3.21-3.fc18.x86_64 is a duplicate with libdb-5.2.36-5.fc17.x86_64
1:openssl-1.0.1c-7.fc18.x86_64 is a duplicate with 1:openssl-1.0.0k-1.fc17.x86_64
rpm-4.10.1-3.fc18.x86_64 is a duplicate with rpm-4.9.1.3-8.fc17.x86_64
rpm-build-libs-4.10.1-3.fc18.x86_64 is a duplicate with rpm-build-libs-4.9.1.3-8.fc17.x86_64
rpm-libs-4.10.1-3.fc18.x86_64 is a duplicate with rpm-libs-4.9.1.3-8.fc17.x86_64
rpm-python-4.10.1-3.fc18.x86_64 is a duplicate with rpm-python-4.9.1.3-8.fc17.x86_64
sqlite-3.7.11-3.fc17.x86_64 is a duplicate with sqlite-3.7.11-2.fc17.x86_64
```

Second, using yum:

```
# yum --releasever=21 distro-sync --nogpgcheck
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, priorities, refresh-packagekit
Setting up Distribution Synchronization Process
http://yum.postgresql.org/9.3/fedora/fedora-21-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
Error: failure: repodata/repomd.xml from pgdg93: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
http://yum.postgresql.org/9.3/fedora/fedora-21-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
```

So, my question is how I get fedup to install, or how I get yum to try a different mirror to upgrade?

Update: "Don't do this" or "you can't do this" answers not required. The above methods are taken from the fedora documentation at https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Upgrading_Fedora_using_yum#Upgrading_Fedora_using_yum_directly and https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FedUp#How_Can_I_Upgrade_My_System_with_FedUp.3F

Answer (score 1):

The differences between OS levels is significant enough that I'd recommend a full installation from the Fedora 20 DVDs.  In my experience, attempting to upgrade an OS, especially through many levels, is frought with problems as there are many situations that cannot be properly tested due to the nearly infinite variations with installations.

Also be aware that replacing your old FC17 with FC20+ packages will not effectively upgrade the system.  This is due to the underlying changes and new dependencies between the two different OS versions.

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't an answer to my question. If I wanted to do a fresh install, I'd do that.

Comment: I actually believe this is an answer....it is not going to be effective and you are better off doing a fresh install.  Also be aware that upgrades between such disparate releases are generally not supported.

Comment: Thanks again for your input, however I'm not going to do this. Note also that your answer is not consonant with the fedora documentation. See https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FedUp#How_Can_I_Upgrade_My_System_with_FedUp.3F and https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Upgrading_Fedora_using_yum#Upgrading_Fedora_using_yum_directly

Comment: @Marcin, updates in Fedora are supported *only* between one version and the next. Skipping one version (i.e., going N to N + 2) has just been approved for support (it *usually* worked, but wasn't really tested).

Answer (score 1):

As @mdpc pointed out, F17 to F20/F21 are significant differences that are likely not to be clean if you were to upgrade, never mind the fact that F20 has been EOL since last june and F21 has been EOL since December of 2015.

Looking at your question, you are trying to install a Fedora 20 package on a Fedora 17 system. That's not a good thing to try and it will fail. If Fedora 17 has a fedup package, then you can try to install it, but I wish you luck in finding it. If you want to try to do a yum upgrade, which will more than likely destroy your system, you can do similar to what you tried, but get to a release that is actually supported. `22` for example.

```
# yum clean all
# yum --releasever=22 distro-sync --nogpgcheck
```

Keeping in mind that you should disable any extra repos that you have. This includes your postgres repo.

Either way, you are *encouraged* to do a clean install. You are only going to put yourself into a world of hurt. As it stands, F20 has been EOL since 2015-06-23. It does not matter what is on the documentation on Fedora's website. If you were to ask their IRC channels, their ask pages, or even their forums, they will all tell you the same thing. **Do a clean install**.